# Hide default properties and show aspect properties on Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm stuck  and I cannot figure out why can achieve this. I'm new to Alfresco, so maybe I'm doing it in a wrong way.

I'm trying to hide default properties on Alfresco Share and only show fields of one of my custom aspects. I mean I want to hide cm:title, cm:name etc.

I'm trying to carry out this by customizing `share-config-custom.xml`. If I only use `<hide>` with default properties (without adding custom fields) these are correctly hidden. If I use `<show>` with my custom properties, both, custom properties and default properties are shown. But the problem is that if I add `<hide>` and `<show>` fields, only default fields are shown, although they are seted as hidden.

Here is an example XML:

```
<config evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:content">
  <forms>
    <form>
      <field-visibility>
        <hide id="cm:title" />
        <hide id="cm:description" />
        <show id="custom:DocumentClass" />
        <show id="custom:DocumentDate" />
      </field-visibility>
    </form>
  </forms>
</config>
```

Thaks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Use the hide fields on the **cm:content** type
2. Add an extra config and instead of the `evaluator="node-type"` make it `evaluator="aspect"`
3. Add your custom aspect in the new config you just created

If the above doesn't work, try adding `replace=true` flag to the **cm:content** config

Comment: Many thanks Tahir. That was something that I had tested, but without replace=true. Now it is working like a charm.